# Is there any way to reduce the size of the embedded font documents in libreoffice?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice

My requirement is that I want to display some local language in my documents. So I enabled the **embedfont** option in the **libreoffice writer**. But after enabling that option the size is getting increased by **2MB**. I want to reduce that size. Is there anyway to reduce the size of that document.Please give me some idea.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The legal way will be just to use embed font sub-set.

But as much as I know LibreOffice does not support this feature.